# Mathematica is not simplifying trignometric functions under Abs although I provide assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, trigonometry

I am trying to simplify a simple expression,

```
(1/2)*((-Pi)*Abs[Sin[t]] - 
   Pi*Abs[Sin[t - 2*Pi]] - 
   2*Pi*Abs[Sin[t - Pi]] + 4)
```

i.e $$ \frac{1}{2} (-2 \pi  \left| \sin  (t-\pi )\right| -\pi  \left| \sin  (t-2 \pi )\right| -\pi  \left| \sin  t\right| +4) $$ 
for $0<t<\pi$, which should be 
$$ \frac{1}{2} (1 -4\pi |\sin(t)|)$$. I have tried various methods, like ComplexExpand and then FullSimplify[] which gives me,

```
  (1/2)*Pi*Sqrt[Sin[t - 2*Pi]^
     2] - Pi*Sqrt[Sin[t - Pi]^
     2] + 2
```

i.e $$ -\pi  \sqrt{((t-\pi ) \sin )^2}-\frac{1}{2} \pi  \sqrt{((t-2 \pi ) \sin )^2}-\frac{1}{2} \pi  \sqrt{(t \sin )^2}+2 $$ 
which I understand shouldn't further simplify as square-root brings in an ambiguity, somehow ComplexExpand is making the expression complicated.

Comment: "I have tried various methods, like ComplexExpand and then FullSimplify[]" Then please show _exactly_ what you did.

Comment: `Assuming[0 < t < 
  Pi, (1/2)*((-Pi)*Abs[Sin[t]] - Pi*Abs[Sin[t - 2*Pi]] - 
     2*Pi*Abs[Sin[t - Pi]] + 4) // Simplify]` evaluates to `2 - 2 Pi Sin[t]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
Simplify[
 (1/2)*((-Pi)*Abs[Sin[t]] - Pi*Abs[Sin[t - 2*Pi]] - 2*Pi*Abs[Sin[t - Pi]] + 4)
 ]
```

> 2 - 2 π Abs[Sin[t]]

?

At least, that's what version 11.3 returns to me.

Comment: Ok let me download the latest Mathematica and try.